# Error using Autofac.Extras.NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, autofac

I'm trying to inject dependencies im my models that NHibernate creates.

What I'm trying to do is the same here: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.br/2008/11/entities-behavior-injection.html

But my container is Autofac.

So, I've found https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.NHibernate/

I saw the post http://chadly.net/2009/05/dependency-injection-with-nhibernate-and-autofac/ that I've think is the origin of the Autofac.Extras.NHibernate.

My problem is that the code in Autofac.Extras.NHibernate and described in Chad post are different.

Looking at the source code I (think) figured out how to set the BytecodeProvider using:

```
Cfg.Environment.BytecodeProvider = new AutofacBytecodeProvider(Container, new DefaultProxyFactoryFactory(), new DefaultCollectionTypeFactory());
```

But now, I'm getting an exception when I tried to retrieve data from database:

[PropertyAccessException: could not set a property value by reflection setter of NHibernate.Autofac2.App_Start.Model.User.Id]

If I comment the line where I set BytecodeProvider the code works.

I created a POC to simulate:

My model:

```
 public class User
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public User(ISomeService someService)
    {
        this._someService = someService;
    }

    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string GetTranslate
    {
        get { return this._someService != null ? this._someService.T(this.Name) : " No Translate"  + this.Name; }
    }
}
```

My mapping:

```
 public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name)
          .Length(16)
          .Not.Nullable();

    }

}
```

Creation of the Autofac container and SessionFactory using Fluent Nhibernate:

```
            // Create your builder.
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>();
        builder.RegisterType<User>().As<IUser>();

        Container = builder.Build();

        SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                                 .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=NHibernate.Autofac;User ID=test;Password=102030;Pooling=True"))
                                 .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MvcApplication>())
                                 .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.Properties.Add("use_proxy_validator", "false"))
                                 .ExposeConfiguration(config =>
                                     {
                                         //config.Properties.Add("proxyfactory.factory_class", "");
                                         Cfg.Environment.BytecodeProvider = new AutofacBytecodeProvider(Container, new DefaultProxyFactoryFactory(), new DefaultCollectionTypeFactory());

                                         new SchemaExport(config).Drop(false, false);
                                         new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
                                     })
                                 .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution that works for me.

Now, I'm using [NHibernate.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.DependencyInjection/).

The IEntityInjector implemenation:

```
    public class EntityInjector : IEntityInjector
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public EntityInjector(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object[] GetConstructorParameters(System.Type type)
    {
        var constructor = type.GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault();

        if (constructor != null)
            return constructor.GetParameters().Select(a => a.ParameterType).Select(b => this._container.Resolve(b)).ToArray();

        return null;
    }
}
```

And in Global.asax:

```
            Initializer.RegisterBytecodeProvider(new EntityInjector(Container));

        SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                                 .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=NHibernate.Autofac;User ID=XXX;Password=XXXX;Pooling=True"))
                                 .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MvcApplication>())
                                 .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.Properties.Add("use_proxy_validator", "false"))
                                 .ExposeConfiguration(config =>
                                     {
                                         new SchemaExport(config).Drop(false, false);
                                         new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
                                     })
                                 .BuildSessionFactory();
```